When you think you got it, think again
The clues below aren't hard to solve, but can you tell me what 3-word phrase that's hidden?

One of me is used to hit the ball hoping to get a home run afterall. (3)  One of me is often cubic shaped and used to store things, sometimes mail it brings. (2)  One of me is used to see how fast people run, definitely not as fast as the bullet from a gun (5)  One of me is something people do automatically everyday, good or bad I should say. (6)  One of me is something people, back in the days, used for transportation with the help of the force of a horse. (6)  One of me is for example a poker term used after the words high and low, I can confirm. (5)  One of me is a communication code used mostly by people when they're in ships for some trips. (5)  One of me is commonly used as transportation at sea, often with feelings of being free. (4)  One of me is similar looking to a horse and many people around the world use me to transport their goods, usually foods. (6)  One of me is a device used to increase electrical voltage or signal strength, it's also used in the initial stage of a rocket launch, to give extra acceleration, we sure wouldn't want deceleration. (7)  One of me is "cloudy" and makes it hard to see the surroundings, sometimes it has led to bad endings. (3)  One of me, you see, is usually thin and grows out from a main branch of a tree. (3)

The answers to the clues are:

 1 BAT (3)
 2 BOX (2)
 3 TIMER (5)
 4 HABIT (6)
 5 WAGON (6)
 6 STAKE (5)
 7 MORSE (5)
 8 BOAT (4)
 9 DONKEY (6)
 10 BOOSTER (7)
 11 FOG (3)
 12 TWIG (3)

 Some of the word lengths (those for 2, 4, 5 and 12 ) don't match, so there's clearly more to it. (The title says as much, too.)

Each answer ...

 ... must be replaced with a rhyming word of the given length. This is clued by the highlighted words in the clues, which also rhyme. There are several ways to do that. One of them is:

 bat ⟶ RAT
 box ⟶ OX
 timer ⟶ TIGER
 habit ⟶ RABBIT
 wagon ⟶ DRAGON
 stake ⟶ SNAKE
 morse ⟶ HORSE
 boat ⟶ GOAT
 donkey ⟶ MONKEY
 booster ⟶ ROOSTER
 fog ⟶ DOG
 twig ⟶ PIG

These are ...

 ... the signs of the Chinese Zodiac, so the three-word phrase we're looking for is Chinese Zodiac Signs.


Just pipped me to it, but I think your #3 should be rot13(gvzre)

Great well done! You got everything correct except the one Stiv mentioned above.

You know, it's so easy to be a fast poster when you don't do things properly. Easy peasy, just push the green button, go out for some shopping ... and then you realize that you're standing at the bus top just in your socks. Will fix, of course. I'll also put my shoes on when I get around to it.

Ah I see I was thinking about ‘famous groups of twelve’ but this group for some reason didn’t hit me nice one!
